# How do I get schedule.present to work in saltstack?

Tags: ubuntu, centos7, salt-stack

I want to have a directory on my salt-master, that keep synced to the windows 7 minion I have running.  I tried using [schedule.present](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.schedule.html), but I've had very little luck.  I'm not sure what my problem with that is, but I also think that this may not be the best way to accomplish my task.

Here's what my environment looks like:

**salt-master**

**OS:** CentOS7

**salt version:** 2016.3.0

---

**salt-minion**

**OS:** Ubuntu 14.04

**salt version:** 2016.3.0

---

Here's my current configuration:

**init.sls**

```
syncFiles:
  schedule.present:
    - function: /home/user/directory
    - seconds: 30
    - splay: 10

/home/user/directory:
  file.recurse:
    - source: salt://source/directory/
```

When I run this, everything returns successfully, and `mirrordirectory` runs the first time as expected, but no times in the future.

The debug output from the minion is this.

```
[INFO  ] Invalid function: mirrordirectory in scheduled job syncFiles.
```

I'm guessing I need to put the function on the minion, but I can't find that anywhere in the documentation.

If there's a way to do this without putting a function on the minion, I'm interested in knowing what it is, but I'd like to at least learn how to run schedules in saltsatck.

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Side Note**

Eventually, this is going to be a Windows 7 minion, instead of ubuntu, I'm just trying to get this to work first.

---

**UPDATE 1**

Here's what I've tried based on the answer below (and it's still not working).

**/srv/salt/mirrordirectory/init.sls**

```
syncFiles:
  schedule.present:
    - function: state.sls
- job_args:
  - testfile
- seconds: 30
- splay: 10
```

**/srv/salt/testfile.sls**

```
/tmp/foo:
  file.recurse:
    - source: salt://files
```

**/srv/salt/top.sls**

```
base:
  '*':
    - mirrordirectory
```

**/srv/salt/files**

This directory contains files to be synced

The master returns all success:

```
myminion:
----------
          ID: syncFiles
    Function: schedule.present
      Result: True
     Comment: Job syncFiles in correct state
     Started: 16:18:22.290216
    Duration: 140.989 ms
     Changes:   

Summary for myminion
------------
Succeeded: 1
Failed:    0
------------
Total states run:     1
```

The debug on the minion shows a problem:

```
[DEBUG   ] Sending event - data = {'fun_args': ['testfile'], 'jid': 'req', 'return': ["No matching sls found for 'testfile' in env 'base'"], 'retcode': 1, 'success': True, 'schedule': 'syncFiles', 'cmd': '_return', 'pid': 24448, '_stamp': '2016-06-15T21:19:57.928894', 'fun': 'state.sls', 'id': 'myminion'}
[DEBUG   ] Handling event tag '__schedule_return'
[INFO    ] Returning information for job: req
```

This line seems to be the problem `["No matching sls found for 'testfile' in env 'base'"]`.  Any idea why it can't find the file?

---

**UPDATE 2**

**/etc/salt/master**

```
interface: 192.168.0.1
user: salt
```

Those are the only two lines in my master config file.  I wanted to test running as a user other than root, and everything had been working fine after I changed some file permissions.  Maybe that's the issue...maybe I missed something.

Comment: I've just tried exactly the same salt configs and it worked like a charm for me. I suspect there might be a problem with your salt master configuration. Did you change it in any way from the default one? Can you please paste it here?

Comment: The only thing that I changed is the ```user: root``` to ```user: salt```.  I'll paste my config file in the question.  Thanks again for all of the help.

Comment: Just in case it was causing the problem, I took out the user: root line, and it's running as root again.  That didn't seem to help.

Comment: I've tried once again on two clean VMs and that worked just fine. Just to rule out any configuration issues - is there a way you can make a test on two clean setups (one centOS and one Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function for schedule.present must be a salt function. In your case probably what you want to do is to use `state.sls`. Here is an example similar to what you have that worked for me:

**foo.sls**

```
syncFiles:
  schedule.present:
    - function: state.sls
    - job_args:
      - testfile
    - seconds: 30
    - splay: 10
```

**testfile.sls**

```
/tmp/foo:
  file.recurse:
    - source: salt://files
```

**top.sls**

```
base:
  '*':
    - foo
```

So, what happens here is - `top.sls` applies `foo.sls` to a minion. `foo.sls` in turn makes a minion apply `testfile.sls` every 30 seconds.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm still having an issue.  I updated the end of my question with my current debug stuff.  It appears it can't find the testfile file.